# Area Route Config is not working in mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I try to use area in mvc 4 but the route config is not working getting error has resources cannot be found "/UserAdmin/Menu/MenuPermissions"

i have created two areas named as "UserAdmin" and "Master". 
my home page has placed in root controller please help me to access the area views

My codes are

1. RouteConfig.cs

   ```
   public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
   {
       routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
       AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
       routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Default",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "LoginPage", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
           namespaces: new[] { "SRR.Controllers" }
       );
   }
   ```
2. UserAdminAreaRegistration.cs

   ```
   public class UserAdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
   {
     public override string AreaName
     {
       get
       {
           return "UserAdmin";
       }
     }

     public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
     {
       context.MapRoute(
           "UserAdmin_default",
           "UserAdmin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }                
       );
     }
   }
   ```
3. call in view page

   ```
      <a href="~/UserAdmin/Menu/MenuPermissions"> </a>
   ```
4. Menu Controller

   ```
   public class MenuController : Controller
   {
   //
   // GET: /UserAdmin/Menu/

   readonly  MenuClass _menu = new MenuClass();

   public ActionResult MenuPermissions()
   {
       Session["username"] = "1001";
       if (Session.Count == 0)
       {
           return RedirectToAction("");
       }
       else
       {
           List<Menu> menuList = new List<Menu>();
           menuList = _menu.GetAllMenuItems();
           return View(menuList);    
       }            
   }
   }
   ```

Thanks in advance

Comment: based on your link  <a href="~/UserAdmin/Menu/MenuPermissions"> </a>, you're saying Menu is controller in under UserAdmin area, is it correct? can you please show me that code of Menu controller?

Comment: Yes i update my question please see it and help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code,

```
public class MenuController : Controller
{
//
// GET: /Menu/

readonly  MenuClass _menu = new MenuClass();

public ActionResult MenuPrivilages()
{
    Session["username"] = "1001";
    if (Session.Count == 0)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("");
    }
    else
    {
        List<Menu> menuList = new List<Menu>();
        menuList = _menu.GetAllMenuItems();
        return View(menuList);    
    }            
}
}
```

your link should be  `<a href="~/UserAdmin/Menu/MenuPrivilages"> </a>` instead of  `<a href="~/UserAdmin/Menu/MenuPermissions"> </a>`

Your structure should look like this

[image]

Comment: I updated my question its not working for any controller please help me

Answer (score 1):

Change your RgisterArea to the below

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
  {
    context.MapRoute(
        "UserAdmin_default",
        "UserAdmin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller="Menu" action = "MenuPermissions", id = UrlParameter.Optional }                
    );
  }
```

Let me know if it worked or not?

Comment: Are you specifying the Routes for the other areas in the RegisterArea Method?